# Memory leaks in Iphone

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks

```
 label = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];
            label.text =labelString; 
            size = [label.text sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"ArialMT" size:14] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(320,9999)  lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
            label.frame = CGRectMake(5, 5, 295, (size.height+25));
```

UIFont leave 256 Bytes leak.

And some other leaks also present in my app related to web kit and Foundation library.

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Prayers" ofType:@"html"];
    NSFileHandle *readHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:path];

    NSString *htmlString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:
                            [readHandle readDataToEndOfFile] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

These lines leave UIKit WebKit and DataDetectorsCore related leaks.

Please suggest any solution for this problem. Total leaked memory is arround 3 KB, can i
 leave this in app or not.

Comment: In the grand scheme of things, 3KB isn't a lot... I am a newbie iPhone developer, but using Appcelerator I usually get 40+ MB of memory leaked (a bug in their framework) and the app will run fine (will crash after a while on older devices). After that experience I switched to ObjC because I would rather track down my memory leaks than someone else's... Anyways, you probably want a more expert opinion, but I don't think 3KB is particularly bad...

Comment: IMO memory leaks aren't that bad if they do not grow with time, forgetting to release a few objects here and there will not kill an app but having memory leaks that increase with time will. So if its a constant 3KB regardless of how long your app runs you can consider ignoring it (that said, personally I never ship stuff with memory leaks out of professional pride) sometimes though memleaks are a symptom of something else so its always good to investigate.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you have leak on the UITableViewCell instances.
You made some custom UITableViewCells, maybe you need to check those UITableViewCells.

Comment: I had checked on instrument it some time it shows this leak and some times not but it definitely throws by UIFont. And One more leak present here becoz of web view (Web kit) I mention in above code.Please Suggest some solution. Thanx for your support.

Answer (score 0):

The UIFont leak you mentioned may not be leak at all. The possibility that UIFont wasn't released is internal caching by UIFont when you use the fontWithName method.

Comment: A leak is determined when there is no detected references to an allocated object. If it was cached, there would be a reference to it, and the Leak detector would not consider it leaked.

Comment: Not entirely; there are any number of games that can be played to hide a pointer from detection by the leaks analysis mechanism.   False positives are rare, but do happen.  False negatives, on the other hand, or common.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that `UIFont` may leak memory when called not from the main thread. Put assertion before your code. This will allow you to catch the error.

```
NSAssert([NSThread isMainThread]);
```